# Can a server find out I am accessing it with a python script? If so, how to hide it?

Tags: python, urllib2

I am trying to read a website using the urllib2 library.
Here is my script:

```
import urllib2

# Get a file-like object for the Python Web site's home page.

def wikitranslate(word):
    translation = ''
    pageURL = ''
    opener = urllib2.build_opener()
    f = opener.open("http://fr.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=" + re.sub(' ', '%20', word.rstrip()))
    # Read from the object, storing the page's contents in 's'.
    s = f.read()
```

I am wondering how the server receives these requests and if it can recognize the fact that it is accessed by a python script rather than through a browser.

If so, is there a way to hide it?

Comment: If you are trying to emulate a certain browser from a python script, I suggest using [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to see what is being sent from your browser and then supplying the same information from your python script.

Comment: @sethflowers: +1 for pointing me at Fiddler. It looks like Kewl Tool®.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The User-Agent field in the header of a url request describes to the web server what browser and system you are using to access the site so the best way to either conceal or identify yourself as a python script request is to change that field.

```
request = urllib2.Request(url,None)
request.add_header('User-Agent','Python Script') # Or 'Not a python script'
```

by default this field is left blank when using `urllib2`

So if you want to conceal your agent simply do not declare it, or you can forcefully declare it to be something deceitful

```
request.add_header('User-Agent','None of your business.')
```

Comment: By default it's left blank as I mentioned, so to conceal it just don't declare this field.

Comment: But any "browser" that doesn't send a user agent is automatically suspicious.

Comment: The question was is there a way to hide it. Not anything about what's suspicious.

Comment: If you want to hide the fact that it's a script accessing it, you don't want to look suspicious.

Comment: Would Google Analytics pick the right browser as having accessed the url if I filled in the User-Agent to let's say Firefox?

Comment: Google Analytics normally doesn't see requests that are made with a script such as yours.

Answer (score 1):

Of course it's detectable, but usually not directly. For example, it could look at the user agent's behavior (accesses the same file every hour, for example) or try to load an iframe+img+javascript to check whether you're actually a webbrowser. It could present a captcha which you have to complete before continuing, and there are a lot of different techniques to prevent external scripts from accessing.

But if you look at one single request, it's a lot harder to detect that it's a script making the request. In fact, it's possible to perfectly mimic a browser. Just not the user behind it.

The bigger question, however, is whether what you are trying to do is proper. There's a reason some websites don't want scripts accessing them.

Comment: The goal here is to write a script that will translate keywords based on the wikipedia 'languages' tab.